# Are certain access modifiers not allowed for instance variables in java?

Tags: java

i have a piece of code like this:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class TestGUI {
        default static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 960;
        default static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 540;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

when i compile the code, the complier says "modifier default not allowed here"

If I remove the keyword `default`, the code compiles without errors.

Replacing `default` with `private` also compiles successfully.

I thought instance variables without a specified access modifier would have the `default` modifier by default.

I'm having trouble understanding why having the `default` modifier gives me errors but not having it doesn't.

Explanations would be appreciated =)

Comment: Since you used `static`, these are not actually instance variables.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the phrase **default access modifier**, it means the access level assumed **by default** when no access modifier is specified which is package-level private (only anything in the same package can see it), it doesn't mean the literral **default** keyword

Comment: @Teedeez is right; default (i.e. package-private) access is what you get if you don't write an access modifier. The `default` keyword is not an access modifier, it is used for the default case in `switch` statements, and for default method implementations in interfaces.

Comment: It's also used to denote the default value for annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, your variables are static final, so not an instance variable and not really a default value (since you can't really change the value of a `final` primitive-typed variable without tricks)

The `default` modifier does not specify that an instance variable has a default value. That's just done as `[access-modifiers] Type name = value`, i.e. `int windowHeight = 960;` A ctor or setter can then overwrite this with your desired value.

In contrast, the `default` modifier is used to declare/define an interface method that has a default *implementation*.

Consider the following example:

```
interface IntSet {
    Set<Integer> getSet();
    default boolean setContains(int x) { return getSet().contains(x); }
}
```

This is useful since it allows an implementor to take advantage of delegation, such as:

```
class MyIntSet implements IntSet {
    private TreeSet<Integer> set;
    public MyIntSet(Set<Integer> s) {
        set = new TreeSet<>(s);
    }
    @Override Set<Integer> getSet() { return set; }
}
```

Note the simplicity here: `setContains` is already implemented correctly, by delegating to `getSet`.

But it also allows an implementor to provide a more efficient implementation:

```
class MyIntSet implements IntSet {
    private TreeSet<Integer> set;
    private int lower, upper;
    public MyIntSet(int lower, int upper) {
        set = new TreeSet<>();
        for(int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) { set.add(i) };
        this.lower = lower;
        this.upper = upper;
    }
    @Override Set<Integer> getSet() { return set; }
    @Override boolean setContains(int x) { return x >= lower && x <= upper; }
}
```

Note that this is more efficient than simply calling `set.contains(x)`.